# is super able to access parent class's attribute

Tags: python

I have following simple code,

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = "789"

    def method1(self):
        return "valueA"


class B(A):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super(B, self).__init__()

    def call_parent_method(self):
        return super().method1()

    def call_parent_value(self):
        return super().value


b = B()
print(b.call_parent_method())
print(b.call_parent_value())
```

`b.call_parent_method()` works well, while `b.call_parent_value()` throws following exception:

```
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'value'
```

I know that `self.value` works,but I just want to know why `super().value` doesn't work.

Comment: You can simply use `self.value`. Also `super()` is used when you are overriding a method. You could have used `self.method1()` as well since you are not overriding `method1`.

Comment: I know that self.value works,but I just want to know why super().value doesn't work.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56896131/why-cant-super-access-the-attribute-in-a-class-in-python . The key is that `super()` doesn't initialize a base class instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you inherit class attributes but you don't inherit instance attributes. They belong to a specific instance of a class.

When you are in class `B`, `value` is an instance attribute of `B`, not `A`. If `value` was a class attribute you would be able to access it using `super().value`, for example:

```
class A:
    value = 5

class B(A):
    def get_value(self):
        return super().value

b = B()
print(b.get_value())
```

Answer (score 1):

Guido van Rossum provide [a pure Python version](http://python.org/download/releases/2.2/descrintro/#superexample) of `super()` , which might make it clear to see how `super()` works (The C implementation details are in `super_getattro()` in [Objects/typeobject.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Objects/typeobject.c#L7270)).

Take a look at the last part of `__getattr__`, we would know that [super() works for class attribute lookup](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super). The above `super().value` is equivalent to `super(B, self).__getattr__("value")`.

```
class Super(object):
    def __init__(self, type_, obj=None):
        self.__type__ = type_
        self.__obj__ = obj

    def __get__(self, obj, cls=None):
        if self.__obj__ is None and obj is not None:
            return Super(self.__type__, obj)
        else:
            return self

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        if isinstance(self.__obj__, self.__type__):
            start_type = self.__obj__.__class__
        else:
            start_type = self.__obj__

        mro = iter(start_type.__mro__)
        for cls in mro:
            if cls is self.__type__:
                break

        # Note: mro is an iterator, so the second loop
        # picks up where the first one left off!
        for cls in mro:
            if attr in cls.__dict__:
                x = cls.__dict__[attr]
                if hasattr(x, "__get__"):
                    x = x.__get__(self.__obj__)
                return x
        raise AttributeError(attr)
```