# Getting private attribute in parent class using super(), outside of a method

Tags: python, super, class-variables

I have a class with a private constant `_BAR = object()`.

In a child class, outside of a method (no access to `self`), I want to refer to `_BAR`.

Here is a contrived example:

```py
class Foo:
    _BAR = object()

    def __init__(self, bar: object = _BAR):
        ...

class DFoo(Foo):
    """Child class where I want to access private class variable from parent."""

    def __init__(self, baz: object = super()._BAR):
        super().__init__(baz)
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work.  One gets an error: `RuntimeError: super(): no arguments`

Is there a way to use super outside of a method to get a parent class attribute?

---

The workaround is to use `Foo._BAR`, I am wondering though if one can use `super` to solve this problem.

Comment: Hi, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56896131/why-cant-super-access-the-attribute-in-a-class-in-python) out.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26318836/getting-parent-private-or-protected-values-from-the-child-class ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: you can't !

I'm not going into much details about `super` class itself here. (I've written a pure Python implementation in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/amirsoroush/5f232a1fc7d5a93a244401249fcec83e) if you like to read.)

But now let's see how we can *call* `super`:

#### 1- Without arguments:

From [PEP 3135](https://peps.python.org/pep-3135/):

> This PEP proposes syntactic sugar for use of the super type to
> automatically construct instances of the super type binding to the
> class that a method was defined in, **and the instance (or class object
> for classmethods) that the method is currently acting upon.**
>
> The new syntax:
>
> ```
> super()
> ```
>
> is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> super(__class__, <firstarg>)
> ```
>
> ...and **`<firstarg>` is the first parameter of the method**

So this is not an option because you don't have access to the "instance".
(Body of the function/methods is **not** executed unless it gets called, so no problem if `DFoo` doesn't exist yet inside the method definition)

#### 2- super(type, instance)

From [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super):

> The zero argument form only works inside a class definition, as the
> compiler fills in the necessary details to correctly retrieve the
> class being defined, as well as accessing the current instance for
> ordinary methods.

What were those necessary details mentioned above? A "type" and A "instance":

We can't pass neither "instance" nor "type" which is `DFoo` here. The first one is because it's not inside the method so we don't have access to instance(self). Second one is `DFoo` itself. By the time the body of the `DFoo` class is being executed there is no reference to `DFoo`, it doesn't exist yet. The body of the class is executed inside a namespace which is a dictionary. **After** that a new instance of type `type` which is here named `DFoo` is created using that populated dictionary and added to the global namespaces. That's what `class` keyword roughly does in its simple form.

#### 3- super(type, type):

> If the second argument is a type, issubclass(type2, type) must be
> true

Same reason mentioned in above about accessing the `DFoo`.

#### 4- super(type):

> If the second argument is omitted, the super object returned is
> unbound.

If you have an unbound super object you can't do lookup(unless for the super object's attributes itself). Remember `super()` object is a descriptor. You can turn an unbound object to a bound object by calling `__get__` and passing the instance:

```py
class A:
    a = 1

class B(A):
    pass

class C(B):
    sup = super(B)
    try:
        sup.a
    except AttributeError as e:
        print(e)  # 'super' object has no attribute 'a'

obj = C()
print(obj.sup.a)  # 1
```

`obj.sup` automatically calls the `__get__`.

And again same reason about accessing `DFoo` type mentioned above, nothing changed. Just added for records. These are the ways how we can call `super`.

Answer (score 4):

Inside of `DFoo`, you cannot refer to `Foo._BAR`  without referring to `Foo`. Python variables are searched in the local, enclosing, global and built-in scopes (and in this order, it is the so called LEGB rule) and `_BAR` is not present in any of them.

Let's ignore an explicit `Foo._BAR`.

Further, it gets inherited: `DFoo._BAR` will be looked up first in `DFoo`, and when not found, in `Foo`.

What other means are there to get the `Foo` reference? `Foo` is a base class of `DFoo`. Can we use this relationship? Yes and no. Yes at execution time and no at definition time.

The problem is when the `DFoo` is being defined, it does not exist yet. We have no start point to start following the inheritance chain. This rules out an indirect reference (`DFoo` -> `Foo`) in a `def method(self, ....):` line and in a class attribute `_DBAR = _BAR`.

It is possible to work around this limitation using a class decorator. Define the class and then modify it:

```
def deco(cls):
    cls._BAR = cls.__mro__[1]._BAR * 2  # __mro__[0] is the class itself
    return cls 

class Foo:
    _BAR = 10

@deco
class DFoo(Foo):
    pass

print(Foo._BAR, DFoo._BAR) # 10 20
```

Similar effect can be achieved with a metaclass.

The last option to get a reference to `Foo` is at execution time. We have the object `self`, its type is `DFoo`, and its parent type is `Foo` and there exists the `_BAR`. The well known `super()` is a shortcut to get the parent.

I have assumed only one base class for simplicity. If there were several base classes, `super()` returns only one of them. The example class decorator does the same. To understand how several bases are sorted to a sequence, see how the MRO works (Method Resolution Order).

My final thought is that I could not think up a use-case where such access as in the question would be required.